# PHP Error encountered in XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I am using [this](https://github.com/robertmain/Treasure-Hunt) code to implement a 'Treasure Hunt' . I have very little idea about the code that I am working with . One thing I am trying to do is make the code work with XAMPP on my PC . I was able to fix the database errors that I was encountering whenever I tried to navigate to **localhost/treasurehunt/admin/login** . What I did was this -

- Set a root username and password for the entire 'thing'
  (using **localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php**)
- Edited the database.php file with appropriate username and password (That of the 'root') .
- Created a database (using **localhost/phpmyadmin**) and changed database.php accordingly .

Now , when I try to navigate to **localhost/treasurehunt/admin/login** page , I am getting an error . I tried fixing this from last two days (by searching on various forums) , but was not of "much" help . The error is as follows -

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$agent

Filename: core/Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code

Line Number: 9


Fatal error: Call to a member function is_mobile() on a non-object in  
C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\treasurehunt\system\core\Loader.php(829) : eval()'d code on  
line 9
```

Is there any way I can fix this . Please tell me which all code samples from which files do you guys need to understand the problem precisely . I will add the code to my question .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: you're trying to invoke a method on something that isn't an object. you need to show the code where this is happening, as per the line numbers in the error message.

Comment: @MarcB . Thanks Marc . I will attach the file Loader.php to the question .

Comment: that's probably part of codeigniter, and probably not relevant. "eval()'d code" is what is relevant. so figure out where this loader.php is being invoked from.

Comment: @MarcB How do I know where is it being invoked from ? Sorry for being such a noob .

Comment: It seems to me that you did not load the class whose method you use.

Comment: What grade is a method is_mobile ()?

Comment: As I said , I have very little idea about the code . I thought there is some problem with my XAMPP configuration settings (Like some problem in php.ini file) . The code is entirely taken from the link I provided . Please instruct me where to search for and what to . I know I am asking a lot . Sorry folks .